# What does Una Excelsior mean?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, grammar-choice, meaning

I'm looking for a good phrase to encapsulate "ever upward, together" and i'd like to use Una, Excelsior

Any thoughts or other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

That does not seem like a good translation to me, for the following reasons:

1. *excelsior* does not really mean “upward,” it means “higher, loftier; more elevated, distinguished” etc. (I get that being “higher” often implies an upward motion, but it's still a different thing.)
2. Besides, *excelsior* is also masculine/feminine singular, so it cannot refer to several people or have an adverbial quality.
3. *una* does mean “together,” but it also simply means “one,” and usually the way it is used implies the “together” meaning. For example: *una cum X, una et Y*, etc. Even something simple like *una venierunt* (they came together) could not be understood in any other way. But in your example, this is not so clear.

So when I read *una excelsior*, my first idea at least is “one (female person) is higher.” Not really the idea.

So, how to improve things?

**Upward** is typically either *sursum* or *sublime*. *Sublime* sounds a little more, well, sublime? but is also a little ambiguous, because it's really a noun meaning “great height” or something to that effect. Therefore I would say *in sublime*, which is also attested. *Sursum* is the standard word for “upward,” but also pretty literal and prosaic. So if you're looking for this phrase to celebrate, say, a mountaineering party or a roofing business, go with *sursum*, if it's a wedding ring, go with *in sublime*.

Alternatively, you could avoid translating “upward” directly and instead use a verb that implies upward motion, like *escendere* or *ascendere* (to ascend, climb, rise up), e.g. *ascendamus* (let us rise up, may we ascend etc).

For **together**, I would recommend *coniunctim* or *coniuncte* (adverbs) or *coniuncti* (if the phrase refers to several people). If you use a verb, *una* would be unproblematic as well (e.g. *una ascendamus*).

Finally, for **ever** I understand this to mean “only upward, never down,” and I would translate this simply as *semper*. (There would be other options like *nihil aliud quam ascendamus* etc., but I feel they would be too heavyweight.) Alternatively, you could leave it out, as you have done in your translation attempt.

So, a possible translation would be: **Coniunctim in sublime**; or: **Una semper ascendamus**.

Comment: I think "upwards" in this sense does not indicate motion, and there's some support for translating *excelsior* thus, in that it's the official translation of the [motto of New York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_of_New_York_(state)).

Answer (score 1):

While *Excelsior*, [the motto of New York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_of_New_York_(state)), is often translated as "ever upward", it doesn't really contain the "ever" part, nor does it really mean "upward", as Sebastian correctly points out. Instead, it really just means "higher [= more elevated], loftier."

That said, if you're thinking about that motto in particular with your English, than there's little reason to change it to something more accurate: the Latin precedes the (inaccurate) English.

But you'll need to change the grammar a bit if you want it to apply to a group of people who are doing something together. There *una* is fine, but *excelsior* will need to be changed to *excelsiores*, the plural, to indicate you're now talking to multiple people.